# Blur on border in react native

Tags: react-native, border, blur

How can i do blur on border such like this in ReactNative on IOS:

[image]

I tried to do it with shadow:

borderRadius: 7,
paddingVertical: 10,
paddingHorizontal: 14,
shadowColor: 'black',
shadowOffset: {
width: 0,
height: 0
},
shadowRadius: 2,
shadowOpacity: 0.2,
backgroundColor: 'white'

But it does not have the same result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apply style

```
dropShadow:{
      shadowColor: '#000',
      shadowOpacity: 0.5,
      shadowRadius: 5,
      elevation: 2,
    }
```

Working example
Link: https://snack.expo.io/@msbot01/referencefor

Full code:

```
import React, { Component} from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet} from 'react-native';


class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
    } 


    render() {
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
              <View style={[{height:100, width:100, borderWidth:0, borderRadius:10},styles.dropShadow]}>

              </View>
                
               
            </View>
        )       
}}


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        justifyContent:'center', 
        alignItems:'center'
    },
    dropShadow:{
      shadowColor: '#000',
      shadowOpacity: 0.5,
      shadowRadius: 5,
      elevation: 2,
    }
});



export default App;
```